# How to get controller name from request culture middle ware in .net core

Tags: api, .net-core, webapi

Is there any way to get controller name from Request Culture Middle ware in .net core.
Below is my code snippet.

```
public class RequestCultureMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RequestCultureMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)
    {
       //Here i need controller name
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [ControllerAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllers.controlleractiondescriptor?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

```
ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerName
```

Can you try this to get controller name?

Comment: How can i access it through Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context?

Comment: string controllerName =context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();